# Access a CodeIgniter controller function without web server

Tags: php, performance, apache, codeigniter, cron

I am currently working on a medium size `CodeIgniter` project.

I have created some functions inside my controllers which are manipulating database tables (create tables from others, delete tables, etc.).

I would like to call these functions periodically thanks to several `cron-scripts`, calling the related URLs with `curl`.

Since the database manipulation could be quite heavy, I would like to know if the fact of using a intermediary (here `Apache`, but any web server) will decrease the performance of the functions.

Could it be possible to call the functions (located inside my controllers) directly with the `PHP` executable ?

Comment: It's quite possible: https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: @Bulk Thanks for that link, these is a pretty good answer ! ;)